# Conversion from member function to friend function

Tags: c++, class, oop, object, uml

I have this assignment to convert all member functions into friend functions and add a copy constructor. I did not really understand the given lecture this week.Please can anyone convert any two (one of the accessor function and other one from the add/multiply block) of the functions here. Just one function and I will do the rest. Thanx in advance

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
class fraction
{
 long num;
 long den;

 public: 
fraction(long,long);
fraction();
~fraction();
void  setNum ( long ); 
void  setDen ( long );
long  getNum ( void );
long    getDen ( void );  

void  print  (void);

void add  (fraction, fraction);
void sub  (fraction, fraction);
void mult (fraction, fraction);
void div  (fraction, fraction);
void inc  (fraction);

}  ;   // end of class fraction

long gcd (long x, long y); 

fraction::fraction(long l_num, long l_den)
{

    num = l_num;
    den = l_den;
}
fraction::fraction()
{

}
fraction::~fraction()
{


}

void fraction::setNum (long  l_num )
 {
  num = l_num ;
 }


void fraction::setDen (long l_den )
 {
  den = l_den ;
 }

long fraction::getDen ( )
 {
  return den ;
 }

long fraction::getNum ( )
 {
  return num ;
 }          

void fraction:: print (void)
{
   cout<<num/gcd(num,den)<<"/"<<den/gcd(num,den) <<endl;
} 

void fraction::add (fraction f1, fraction f2)
{ 
  num = (f1.getNum ( ) * f2.getDen ( )) + ( f1.getDen ( ) * f2.getNum ( ) );
  den = (f1.getDen ( ) * f2.getDen ( ));
}  

void fraction::sub (fraction f1, fraction f2)
{ 
  num = (f1.getNum ( ) * f2.getDen ( )) - ( f1.getDen ( ) * f2.getNum ( ) );
  den = (f1.getDen ( ) * f2.getDen ( ));
}  

 void fraction::mult (fraction f1, fraction f2)
{ 
  num = (f1.getNum ( ) * f2.getNum ( )); 
  den = (f1.getDen ( ) * f2.getDen ( ));

}  

void fraction::div(fraction f1, fraction f2)
{ 

 num = (f1.getNum ( ) * f2.getDen ( )); 
 den = (f1.getDen ( ) * f2.getNum ( ));
 }

void fraction::inc (fraction f1)
{ 
  num = (f1.getNum ( )) + ( f1.getDen ( ) );
 den = (f1.getDen ( ) );

 }  


long gcd (long x, long y)
{
 return (x == 0) ? y :  gcd (y%x, x); 
} 

int main ( )
{
 //  define seven instances of the class fraction
 fraction f1(1L,2L),f2(3L,4L),f3, f4,f5,f6, f7;

 //set values for the numerator and denominator to f1 and print them
 //f1.setDen( 2L);
 //f1.setNum( 0L);
 f1.print();

 //set values for the numerator and denominator to f2 and print them
 //f2.setDen( 4L);
 //f2.setNum( 3L); 
 f2.print();

 f3.add( f1, f2);
 f3.print();

 f4.sub( f1, f2);
 f4.print();

 f5.mult( f1, f2);
 f5.print();

 f6.div( f1, f2);
 f6.print();

 f7.inc(f1);
 f7.print();

 return 0;

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The copy constructor can look like

```
fraction( const fraction & );
```

and be defined as

```
fraction::fraction( const fraction &rhs ) : num( rhs.num ), den( rhs.den )
{
}
```

I would declare arithmetic functions as returning an object of type fraction.

For example

```
friend const fraction add( const fraction &, const fraction & );
```

and define it as

```
const fraction add( const fraction &lhs, const fraction &rhs )
{
    return fraction( lhs,getNum() * rhs.getDen() + rhs.getNum() * lhs.getDen(), 
                     lhs.getDen() * rhs.getDen() );
}
```

Take into account that functions getNum and getDen have to be declared as

```
long  getNum() const;
long  getDen() const;
```

Function inc can be declared either as

```
friend const fraction inc( fraction & );
```

or as

```
friend fraction & inc( fraction & );
```

depending on whether it simulates the post-increment or pre-increment operation.

Comment: How can I write the getNum() function?

Comment: @user2951660 long fraction::getNum() const { return num; }

Comment: Blagodarya.. Thanx vlad

Comment: but getName and setName can not be converted to friend functions isnt it?

Comment: @Yourfavouritenoob If you want you may make them friend functions. But I do not see a sense in this. Usually getters and setters are member functions.

Comment: Can you give me an example how to write a set friend function. I know it doesnot make sense but it is an assignment, I have already missed it,it wont be graded but I am just doing it to expand my knowledge

Comment: @Yourfavouritenoob friend void setNum( fraction &f, long value ) { f.num = value; } friend long getNum( const fraction &f ) { return f.num; }

Comment: @Yourfavouritenoob You should declare the functions with specifier friend inside the class and define them outside the class without the specifier friend.